If $f:D\to D$ is analytic, bijective and $f(0)=0$, then $f(z)=cz$ for some $|c|=1$?
Let $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$ and $f:D\to D$ an analytic, bijective function with $f(0)=0$. Is it true that $f(z)=cz$ for some $c\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|c|=1$?
I think it can be proved using Schwarz's lemma and the fact that $f^{-1}$ is also analytic, but I'm wondering if there is another proof that doesn't use the latter.

Schwarz Lemma is cute and it simplifies many proofs. Why are you allergic to it?

Schwarz lemma is fine, but using that the inverse is analytic feels artificial here

Do you know (i.e., "can you use") that every holomorphic bijection from the disk to itself is (the restriction of) a Möbius transformation?

@AndrewD.Hwang That is exactly what I'm trying to prove, and I figured that it follows from the statement above. To give some context, such characterization of analytic bijections from D to D is an exercise in chapter 3 of Marshall's Complex Analysis book, and so far we only have theorems such as the identity and maximum principles and Schwarz's Lemma

Ok, here is a solution that only uses the open mapping theorem, the maximum principle and Schwarz lemma.
First, we show that $|f(z)|\to 1$ as $|z|\to 1$.
Suppose not, that is, suppose there exists a sequence $\{z_{n}\}_{n\geq 1}\subseteq D$, $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and $r<1$ such that $|z_{n}|\to 1$ and $|f(z_{n})|\leq r$ for all $n\geq N$.
Then by compactness there exists a subsequence $\{z_{n_{k}}\}_{k\geq 1}$ such that $f(z_{n_{k}})\to w$ and $|w|<1$.
On the other hand, $f$ is surjective so there exists $z\in D$ such that $f(z)=w$.
Moreover, $f$ is non-constant because it is surjective, so it is open.
Thus choosing $\delta>0$ small enough so that $B(z,\delta)$ (the open disk centered at $z$ with radius $\delta$) is contained in $D$, we conclude that $f(B(z,\delta))$ contains $B(w,\varepsilon)$ for some $\varepsilon>0$.
In particular, for $k$ sufficiently large we have $z_{n_{k}}\not\in B(z,\delta)$ and $f(z_{n_{k}})\in B(w,\varepsilon)$, thus there exists $z^{\star}\in B(z,\delta)$ with $f(z^{\star})=f(z_{n_{k}})$, which contradicts that $f$ is injective.
Now, as $f(0)=0$, the function $g(z)=f(z)/z$ is analytic in $D$ and $|g(z)|\to 1$ as $|z|\to 1$, thus $|g(z)|\leq 1$ by the maximum principle.
The same argument applies to $1/g(z)$, thus $|f(z)|=|z|$ in $D$, and therefore $f(z)=cz$ for some $|c|=1$ by the equality case in Schwarz's lemma.
